# Click an ImageButton which belongs to a CardView inside a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-recyclerview

**SOLVED**

I've fixed it mixing your answers, so I've decided to write down on here.

The key has been the `ViewHolder` constructor:

I have deleted the `setOnClickListener()` and the `onClick()` methods and I´ve defined this inner class in my `ObjectAdapter.java`.

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

     public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            card_first_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), object.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            card_second_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Forward button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
     }
}
```

And that´s all. The rest of the class is the same.

The `ObjectFragment.java` is:

```
public class ObjectFragment extends Fragment {

    public void ObjectFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this Fragment
        return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_object, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        final ArrayList<Object> objects = initializeList();

        if(!objects.isEmpty()) {   
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.objects_recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDivider(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));

            final ObjectAdapter objectAdapter = new ObjectAdapter(objects, R.layout.card_object);    
            recyclerView.setAdapter(objectAdapter);
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Object> initializeList() {
        ArrayList<Object> objects= new ArrayList<>();    
        objects.add(new Object(...));    
        return objects;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much guys.

---

**Original question**

I have a `RecyclerView` which contains some `CardViews`. This `CardViews` have two different `ImageButton` which make different things when you click them (obvious).

Here is the `card_object.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/object_card"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:clickable="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/object_card_first_button"
                android:src="@drawable/contact_100px"
                android:maxHeight="25dp"
                android:maxWidth="25dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@color/transparentBackgroundPrimary"
                android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="54dp"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/forward_100px"
                android:maxHeight="25dp"
                android:maxWidth="25dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@color/transparentBackgroundPrimary"
                android:id="@+id/object_card_second_button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is the main code of my `ObjectAdapter.java`:

```
public class ObjectAdapter 
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ObjectAdapter.ViewHolder> 
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<Object> objects;
    private int itemLayout;
    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener;

    public ObjectAdapter(ArrayList<Object> objects, int itemLayout) {
        this.objects = objects;
        this.itemLayout = itemLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(itemLayout, viewGroup, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        this.onClickListener = listener;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(onClickListener != null) {
        onClickListener.onClick(view);
    } 
}
```

My `ObjectFragment.java` is the next:

```
public class ObjectFragment extends Fragment {

    public void ObjectFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this Fragment
        return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_object, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        final ArrayList<Object> objects = initializeList();

        if(!objects.isEmpty()) {   
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.objects_recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDivider(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));

            final ObjectAdapter objectAdapter = new ObjectAdapter(objects, R.layout.card_object);
            objectAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Here I can manage my Object attributes,
                    // but no the ImageButtons itselves
                }
            });

            recyclerView.setAdapter(objectAdapter);
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Object> initializeList() {
        ArrayList<Object> objects= new ArrayList<>();    
        objects.add(new Object(...));    
        return objects;
    }
}
```

I can obtain the values of the `Object` attributes (name, title, whatever), and click on the `CardView` and so on, but I'm not able to make that the `ImageButton`have their own onClick.

I don't know if using `android:onClick()` it would be possible to display the information of a specific card, but this is another thing.

So my question is how can I make that this two buttons do have their own `OnClickListener`, where I should declare it and how can handle the information of each item of the `RecyclerView` after that (this part is almost achieved).

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the button event clicks in your ViewHolder class like this.

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

public ButtonImage firstButton;
public ButtonImage secondButton;

public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    firstButton = (ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.object_card_first_button);
    firstButton = (ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.object_card_second_button);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
 int id = view.getId();
 switch (id){
       case R.id.object_card_first_button:
       // button event
       break;
       case R.id.object_card_second_button
       // button event
       break;

 }

}
```

Comment: I've tried and the problem doing this is that the button event don't know which `CardView` is the owner of the `ImageButton`. The only way is passing the index of the `CardView` which I'm clicking and it's not possible by this way. I think.

Comment: You can get the position in your RecycleViewAdapter - @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
        
    }

Comment: I don't know how to do exactly. Could you write some example code?

Comment: @ÓscarGrande this answer should work for you. In the onClick method use **getAdapterPosition()** to identify the clicked position

Comment: Thanks @MuchOverflow. I didn't know it and it has been key!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton).setOnClickListener(...); should do the job.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: I have added the `v.findViewById(...).setOnClickListener(...)` inside the first `onClick(...)`, because is the only way to get the view of the `CardView`, so I have to click first the card and then the button. It is a solution, but not the best one.

Comment: You have to add my line in the onCreateViewHolder of your adapter, you'll have all the informations needed I think.

Comment: You could be interrested by v.getParent();

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(itemLayout, viewGroup, false);

    view.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id. object_card_first_button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                something?
            }
        });

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I have a solution that works for me, after a lot of trial and error, and is easier than the others. Keeping the ViewHolder RecycleronClickListeners the same and the adapter the same:

in onClick() in the Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position, int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view;
            button.setImageResource(resource); // Or any other imagebutton action
            break;
        case R.id.button_2:
            ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view;
            button.setImageResource(resource); // Or any other imagebutton action
            break;
```