# What is this in a recyclerView click handling?

Tags: java, android

Im confused how click handling works here. Why are we `this` from main activity to `GreenAdapter` constructor and set `ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener` to `this`.

How exactly is click handling working in RecyclerView.

The NumberViewHolder is only created or called 10 times here and its recycled for the rest of the 100 item views. So how is onClick(View v) distinguished between the 100 different list item views. We only set itemView.setOnClickListener on the 10 item Views created.

```
public class GreenAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GreenAdapter.NumberViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = GreenAdapter.class.getSimpleName();


    final private ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener;


    private static int viewHolderCount;

    private int mNumberItems;


    public interface ListItemClickListener {
        void onListItemClick(int clickedItemIndex);
    }


    public GreenAdapter(int numberOfItems, ListItemClickListener listener) {
        mNumberItems = numberOfItems;
        mOnClickListener = listener;
        viewHolderCount = 0;
    }


    @Override
    public NumberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.number_list_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
        NumberViewHolder viewHolder = new NumberViewHolder(view);

        viewHolder.viewHolderIndex.setText("ViewHolder index: " + viewHolderCount);

        int backgroundColorForViewHolder = ColorUtils
                .getViewHolderBackgroundColorFromInstance(context, viewHolderCount);
        viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColorForViewHolder);

        viewHolderCount++;
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: number of ViewHolders created: "
                + viewHolderCount);
        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NumberViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "#" + position);
        holder.bind(position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNumberItems;
    }


    class NumberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {

        // Will display the position in the list, ie 0 through getItemCount() - 1
        TextView listItemNumberView;
        // Will display which ViewHolder is displaying this data
        TextView viewHolderIndex;


        public NumberViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            listItemNumberView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_number);
            viewHolderIndex = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_view_holder_instance);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        void bind(int listIndex) {
            listItemNumberView.setText(String.valueOf(listIndex));
        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            mOnClickListener.onListItemClick(clickedPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

In mainActivity, i have

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GreenAdapter.ListItemClickListener {
...
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mNumbersList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_numbers);


        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mNumbersList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        mNumbersList.setHasFixedSize(true);


        mAdapter = new GreenAdapter(NUM_LIST_ITEMS, this);
        mNumbersList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
 @Override
    public void onListItemClick(int clickedItemIndex) {

        if (mToast != null) {
            mToast.cancel();
        }


        String toastMessage = "Item #" + clickedItemIndex + " clicked.";
        mToast = Toast.makeText(this, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        mToast.show();
    }
...
}
```

Comment: here `this` keyword is used to mention implemented Interface. Actually, it refer to an MainActivity, which is an ListItemClickListener. And this is java basics.

Comment: ok, thanks. the NumberViewHolder is only created or called 10 times here and its recycled for the rest of the item views. So how is onClick(View v) distinguished between the 100 different list item views

Comment: why you ask us to explain someone else's code/ Why don't you ask the one who wrote it?

Comment: because i'm learning from online. so i have difficulty understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ViewHolder` mission is to maintain your different views (100 in this case) available. This is crazy for the device performance, so the `RecyclerView` 'recycles' them 10 by 10 (or whatever). The `NumberViewHolder` is called for each of this 10 different elements, so the system knows which element is referred when you click on it.

This is the reason why you set the `itemView.setOnClickListener(this);` on it, because each `View` has to have his own.

From the [Android Developers Guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html):

**`RecyclerView.ViewHolder`**

> A ViewHolder describes an item view and metadata about its place
>   within the RecyclerView.

So everything you want to set for your `View` has to be defined in there, then the `RecyclerView` will do the 'dirty job' of apply it for all the items.

Edit: Here you have a similar question I asked more than a year ago about the same thing: [Click an ImageButton which belongs to a CardView inside a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607524/click-an-imagebutton-which-belongs-to-a-cardview-inside-a-recyclerview)

Comment: ok, thanks, i got one more qn. when i call super(itemView), the final itemView variable of RecyclerView.ViewHolder class is being initialized to the itemView we pass in the super call, right ?

Comment: Because you are extending the functionality of another class (`RecyclerView.ViewHolder` in this case), you have to 'do' first the parent class methods and then whatever you want in your custom `ViewHolder`. So more or less you are right.